# How to express $\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{\binom{j-\frac{1}{2}}{j}}{2 j+2 k+1}$ as an explicit function of $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to solve the period of a pendulum and right now I'm at
$$T=\frac{4}{\omega _0} \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \large(\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k} \left(\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{\binom{j-\frac{1}{2}}{j}}{2 j+2 k+1}\right) u_0^{2k}\large)$$

The next step is to get rid of the inner infinite sum $$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{\binom{j-\frac{1}{2}}{j}}{2 j+2 k+1}$$

The binomial coefficient can be broken into half factorials like $$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{\frac{(j-\frac{1}{2})!}{j!(\frac{-1}{2})!}}{2 j+2 k+1}$$

which can be simplified into $$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{(2j)!}{2^{2j}j!^2(2 j+2 k+1)}$$

I'm really not sure what to do next. Mathematica says it should be $\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k+1}k!^2}\pi$, but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Are you asking for the partial sum ?

Comment: No, I'm asking how to simplify the last infinite sum to be an explicit function of k.

Comment: My end goal here is to derive the series

$$T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}\big(1+\frac{1}{16} \theta_0^2 + \frac{11}{3072} \theta_0^4 + ...\big)$$

but that bottom sum is causing me a lot of trouble.

Comment: What is $\theta$ supposed to be ?

Comment: The initial angular displacement.

Comment: Your comment to @metamorphy is fine. You might consider to provide it as an answer. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^\infty}&\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2j+2k+1}\binom{j-\frac{1}{2}}{j}}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{j}(-1)^j\int_{0}^{1}z^{2j+2k}\,dz\tag{1}\\
> &=\int_0^1z^{2k}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{j}(-1)^jz^{2j}\,dz\\
> &=\int_0^1\frac{z^{2k}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\,dz\tag{2}\\
> &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2k}t\,dt\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}\right)^{2k}\,dt\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2k+1}}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{j=0}^{2k}\binom{2k}{j}(-1)^je^{2i(j-k)}t\,dt\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\pi}{2^{2k+1}}\binom{2k}{k}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1)  we use an integral representation to get rid of the denominator. We also use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (2) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)*.
- In (3) we use the substitution $z=\sin t, dz = \cos t\, dt$.
- In (4) we represent $\sin  t$   using *[Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Derivation_from_Euler's_formula)*.
  We  also  use the  symmetry  of the sine function and  integrate from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
- In (5) we use the binomial theorem.
- In (6) we note $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{int}\,dt =0$  if $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ and have therefore only to consider the term with $j=k$.

> Recalling  the binomial  identity $\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2k}}\binom{2k}{k}$, we obtain from (6)
>   \begin{align*}
> T&=\frac{4}{\omega_{0}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}\frac{\pi}{2^{2k+1}}\binom{2k}{k}u_{0}^{2k}\\
> &=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_{0}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^2(-1)^k\left(\frac{u_0}{4}\right)^{2k}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>
> In (7) we see  the coefficients of the series are squared *[central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)*. This sequence is archived in OEIS as *[A002894](https://oeis.org/A002894)*. Since there is no closed form of (7) given, we rather don't expect it.

Answer (score 1):

As $\dfrac{(2j)!}{2^{2j}j!^2}=\dfrac{(2j-1)!!}{(2j)!!}=(-1)^j\dbinom{-1/2}{j}$, the last sum is equal to $$\int_0^1 x^{2k}(1-x^2)^{-1/2}\ dx=\frac12\mathrm{B}\Big(k+\frac12,\frac12\Big)=\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}\frac{\pi}{2},$$
and your expression for $T$ leads to something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) (as one might expect).

Comment: So I understand where that integral comes from, but I don't really understand what $\frac12\mathrm{B}\Big(k+\frac12,\frac12\Big)$ means or how you go from that to $\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}\frac{\pi}{2}$. Could you elaborate on how to evaluate that integral?

Comment: @NevanLowe: It is [Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) - a "tool" for this kind of integrals (the integral can be evaluated an elementary way - via induction on $k$ and integration by parts - but I'm too lazy for that ;).

Comment: I actually found a way to evaluate it without using the Beta function. I did a substitution $x=\sin(\phi)$ which causes the square root to disappear and you're left with $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(\phi)^{2k} dx$. Then using the sine power reduction you can end up with a constant term of $\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\binom{2k}{k}$ and a bunch of even cosine harmonics which are all zero when integrated from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.